# How to get the value of <label> tags from layout xml files?

Tags: layout

I have a custom block in my layout file like this:

```
<block type="xxx/xxx" name="xxx" template = "bar.phtml">
<label>Foo</label>
</block>
```

How do I get the value of label from bar.phtml ?

Please note I do not want to use setData function to set my variable and pass it.
I want to extract the value inside  tags from the phtml (or anywhere else). I hope its clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered on Stackoverflow. It seems there is no direct function to achieve this.

Full answer may be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30176543/1184359